# Geolocation not working for certain locations

Tags: geolocation

We have a strange issue with geolocations in Salesforce, We have activated the data integration and geolocation based on billing address. While this works well in many countries, it does appear that latitude and longitude are not being populated for certain locations.

Examples of locations that are not recognized and return a 0;0 for latitude and longitude are Seoul (South Korea), any city in Bangladesh (including big ones like Dhaka, Chittagong etc), any city in Vietnam (including Hanoi, HCMC etc), Hong Kong etc. For some of those places it feels a latitude / longitude based on city should be available at a minimum (even if the rest of the address is an unrecognizable mess).

We tried to find some explanations for why those locations are not included, including maybe a list of countries not covered by the geolocation service but we came back empty handed.

Is there anything we are missing here and that explains why some of those locations are not being populated?

---

Added Feb 1: as requested, below are some examples of addresses for which geolocation fails (*with city in italic* and **country in bold**).

Example 1: Flat A14, 4/F., Proficient Ind. Centre,6 Wang Kwun Rd., Kowloon Bay, *Kowloon*, **Hong Kong**

Example 2: Units 401-2 & 410-421, 4/F, New Mandarin Plaza, Tower B, 14 Science Museum Road, T.S.T.East, *Kowloon*, **Hong Kong**

Example 3: Kaicha Bari, Ashulia, Savar, *Dhaka*, 1340, **Bangladesh**

Example 4: 301 Vu Xuan Thieu, Long Bien, *Hanoi*, **Viet Nam**

Example 5: 8th Floor Olympia Bldg, 196 Jamstl-dong, Songpa-Gu, *Seoul*, 138220, **Korea, Republic of**

Some of the addresses are quite specific and we would not necessarily expect a close match, but it feels a geolocation on city should at least be possible for the above.

Comment: Can you provide some example addresses which result in a lat/lng of 0,0?